# Catch errors at closures

Tags: swift

I want to catch errors at an completion handler so that the caller can catch them. I have the following code:

```
private func data_request(url : String, params : String, regularRequest : Bool, completionHandler: @escaping (_ json: Any) -> ()){
        let buildUrl = BuildUrl().createUrl(url: url, regularRequest: regularRequest);

        if(buildUrl.1){
            print("There is something wrong with creating the url");
        }

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: buildUrl.0)!

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        let paramString = (params != "") ? params : ""
        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in

            if data == nil {
                print("dataTaskWithRequest error: \(error)")
                return
            } else {

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                    completionHandler(json)

                } catch {
                    if let data = data,
                        let html = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                        print(html)
                    }
                    print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
                }

            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

It returns json, but is it possible to throw errors? For example when the data == nil, throw an error and catch it on the caller side?

The caller side:

```
func insertData(roomName : String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ error : Bool, _ message : String) -> ()) {
    do {

        let params = "name=/(roomName)";

        data_request(url: createAndJoinRoom, params: params,regularRequest: true) { json in

        completionHandler(error, message)
    };
} catch {

    }   
}
```

The actual caller:

```
ApiManager().insertData(roomName: "test") { (Bool, String) in

}
```

I want an catch block or another construction at my "actual caller" and handle the error there. What I thought was that I modify all the errors at the insertData method, so that I can catch one error with different error messages.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `throw` in conjunction with completion handlers.

An alternative is to use an enum with associated types

```
enum Result {
    case success, failure(Error)
}
```

Or more generic to be able to pass different but distinct return types

```
enum Result<T> {
    case success(T), failure(Error)
}
```

Then you can pass a single type in the completion handler

```
... completionHandler: @escaping (Result) -> ()) { ...
```

and process the returned value

```
... { result in 
       switch result {
       case .success : print("success")
       case .failure(let error) :  print(error)
       }
    }
```

This is a very convenient and efficient way